# ¿Cómo puedo rellenar un vector e imprimirlo de forma recursiva?

Tags: array, c, recursión

En clase el profesor nos pidió hacer un ejercicio en el que sacáramos los valores máximos y mínimos de un vector de enteros de forma recursiva, esa parte del código funciona correctamente, pero también añadió que si podíamos, iniciáramos el vector de forma recursiva, lo estuve haciendo y al parecer también funciona, mi problema es que al probarlo en clase me di cuenta de que si intentaba imprimir el vector en la misma función que lo rellenaba obtenía resultados muy extraños, sin embargo la variable que marcaba la posición del vector y la que guardaba el valor que quería introducirle estaban bien y tenían los valores esperados. Este es el código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void MaxMin (int vector[], int i, int j, int k, int z, int Max, int Min);
void RellenarVector (int vector[], int p, int i);

int main()
{
    int Max, Min;
    int i=4, p=0;
    int *vector;
    int j=0,k=0,z=0;
    printf("Introduzca el numero de elementos que quiere que tenga el vector:\n");
    scanf("%d", &i);
    fflush(stdin);
    if((vector = (int*)malloc(i*sizeof(int)))!=NULL)
    {
        RellenarVector(vector, p, i);
        MaxMin (vector, i,j,k,z,Max, Min);
        printf("%d\n", vector[0]);
        printf("%d\n", vector[1]);
        printf("%d\n", vector[2]);
        printf("%d\n", vector[3]);
        printf("%d\n", vector[4]);
        
    }
    return 0;
}

void MaxMin (int vector[], int i, int j, int k, int z,int Max, int Min)
{
    if(k<(i-1))
    {
        printf("ciclo\n");
        
        if(vector[j]<vector[k+1])
        {
            j=k+1;
        }
        if(vector[z]>vector[k+1])
        {
            z=k+1;
            Min=vector[z];
        }   
        k++;
        MaxMin(vector, i,j, k ,z, Max,Min);
    }
    else
    {
        Max=vector[j];
        Min=vector[z];
        printf("El número máximo del vector será %d y el mínimo %d\n", Max, Min);
    }
    
}

void RellenarVector (int Vector[], int p, int i)
{
    int j;
    if(p<i)
    {
        printf("Introduzca un valor para el vector:\n");
        scanf("%d", &j);
        Vector[p]=j;
        p++;
        printf("%d\n",j);
        printf("%d\n",p);
        printf("%d\n",Vector[(p)]);
        RellenarVector(Vector, p, i);
    }
    if(p==i)
    {
        printf("Vector rellenado\n");
        p=0;
    }
}
```

Le he añadido algunos printf para ver los valores que iban tomando las variables ¿Alguien sabría decirme porque se imprimen mal los valores dentro de esa función?

Answer (score 0):

> mi problema es que al probarlo en clase me di cuenta de que si intentaba imprimir el vector en la misma función que lo rellenaba obtenía resultados muy extraños

Esos resultados extraños de los que hablas no son tal cosa. Lo que sucede es que estás leyendo una posición que todavía no has inicializado

```
    printf("Introduzca un valor para el vector:\n");
    scanf("%d", &j);
    Vector[p]=j;
    p++;
    printf("%d\n",j);
    printf("%d\n",p);
    printf("%d\n",Vector[(p)]); 
    RellenarVector(Vector, p, i);
```

Fíjate que incrementas `p` antes de la secuencia de `printf`. Dado que `p` es el índice, el resultado final es que guardas algo en `p` para, a continuación, mostrar lo que se encuentran en `p+1`